# PDOException - Connection Failed - Could not find driver - PHP5/SQLite/Ubuntu

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I am having a baffling issue.  I've correctly set up PHP5/SQLite before. However, this time it's not working.

The basic expectation of functionality is that I make a generic DB connection using:

```
$dblocation = "path/to/database.db";
$dbConn = new PDO("sqlite:" . $dblocation);
```

From there I am getting the

> Connection Failed: Could not find driver.

I have done the following to resolve this.

1. Checked documentation with: `php -a -c /etc/php5/cli/php.ini` and `phpinfo()`

   ```
   sqlite3

   SQLite3 support => enabled
   SQLite3 module version => 0.7-dev
   SQLite Library => 3.8.2
   ```
2. Checked available drivers:

   ```
   php > print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());
   Array
   (
      [0] => mysql
      [1] => sqlite
   )
   php >
   ```
3. Using Apache2, enabled the `pdo` and `pdo_sqlite`

   With that, I don't need to uncomment the extension line in the PHP.ini file.  If I do uncomment it, I get the expected unable to unregister error that comes when you have two attempts to load.
4. Removed all PHP PDO installs and reinstalled.
5. Removed PHP itself and reinstalled.

None of these have helped.

Like I have said, I have been able to get this to function correctly before, so I am not sure what is wrong here.  Hopefully, somebody has a more solid answer than what I can find.  From what I am seeing everything appears to be configured correctly.

Any assistance anybody can provide would be very appreciated.

Comment: Is it a command-line app or a web-based one?

Comment: Did you install `php5-sqlite` package on ubuntu? This is not sqlite CLI.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález - It's a class file being called by a cron job every minute.  However, I get the same behavior if I sudo php it from the command line.

Comment: @Parfait - Yes, I used apt-get to install the php5-sqlite package.

Comment: @Parfait

Thanks for that.  I copied my apache2 directory as nopache Yes...  Hilarious...

I also disabled the php5 pdo_sqlite module with sudo php5dismod pdo_sqlite.  It didn't remove itself from link in conf.d, so I manually deleted it.

Using  php -a -c /etc/php5/nopache/php.ini, I get the unregister_driver error.

If I removed the ini file, I don't get that error.  So, it looks as though you are correct, the problem is in the Apache2 file.  In my nopache directory, I'm trying to load it either twice or out of order.  In the apache, it's just not loading.  Correct?

Comment: @Parfait I think I have my act together.  I ran in the PHP interactive command line.  I executed a PDO creation and query.  I was able to get results.  I'll look at my apache2 config.

Comment: Go ahead and re-word your question and show apache2 config is the issue. Even tag apache2.

Comment: You didn't really answer my question. `cron` is best suited at running command-line stuff but I guess you're using it to run an HTTP client.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that PHP CLI uses a different ini than the one used by apache. Try to run an `phpinfo();` via the webserver. This should tell you more info.

Comment: Thanks!  I've mirrored any changes made to CLI to Apache2 as well.